# Flatten SciPy lil_matrix without converting to dense to avoid memory error

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, flatten

Given:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
print(np.__version__, scipy.__version__) # numpy: 1.23.5 scipy: 1.11.3
```

I would like to flatten or squeeze my sliced array without converting it to dense in order to avoid memory error:

```
mtx=scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((int(2e8), int(4e9)), dtype=np.float32) # very large lil_matrix
mtx[:int(4e6), :int(7e4)]=np.random.rand(int(4e6), int(7e4))
flat_mtx=mtx.getrowview(0).flatten() # sliced example: row: 0
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'lil_matrix' object has no attribute 'flatten'
```

For smaller sizes, I can alternatively do `mtx.getrowview(0).toarray().flatten()` or a faster approach of `np.squeeze(sp_mtx.getrowview(0).toarray())` but for larger sizes, I do not want to convert to dense `numpy` array.

What is the easy and memory efficient approach to flatten or squeeze a `scipy` sparse `lil_matrix`?

Answer (score 2):

Sparse matrices like lil_matrix work only with 2 dimensional tensors, so it doesn't make sense to flatten it to a single dimension. For this reason it's not really supported. What's your usage downstream?

I suggest reshaping it into a single row, and querying its entries along that row:

```py
flat_mtx = mtx.reshape([1,-1])
first_entry, last_entry = flat_mtx[0,0], flat_mtx[0,-1]
```

Comment: `getrowview` should be 1 row already.

Answer (score 0):

A more modest lil matrix:

```
In [245]: mtx = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((10,10), dtype=np.float32)     
In [246]: mtx
Out[246]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 0 stored elements in List of Lists format>

In [248]: arow = mtx.getrowview(0)    
In [249]: arow
Out[249]: 
<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 0 stored elements in List of Lists format>
```

This is still a lil matrix.  As you found it does not have a `flatten` method.  You found the `getrowview` in the `lil` docs, but you didn't find `flatten`, did you?  Read the actual documentation, not your wishes.

```
In [250]: arow.flatten
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[250], line 1
----> 1 arow.flatten

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_base.py:771, in spmatrix.__getattr__(self, attr)
    769     return self.getnnz()
    770 else:
--> 771     raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")

AttributeError: flatten not found
```

Also from the docs, you see that `lil` has 2 attributes, `data` and `rows`, both object dtype arrays containing lists:

```
In [251]: arow.data, arow.rows
Out[251]: (array([list([])], dtype=object), array([list([])], dtype=object))
```

The `lil` format is unique in that it's possible to get a `view` (in the ndarray sense) for rows.  Other sparse formats don't.  There isn't for example a `columnview`.

The outer object array represents the `row` layer, the inner lists are the columns. There's no 1d representation of a sparse array.

But why do you want a `flatten`.  Sparse matrix, in the pattern of `np.matrix` is only 2d, so flatten does not mean anything.

To belabor the point,

2d dense array:

```
In [253]: arow.toarray()
Out[253]: array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

1d:

```
In [254]: arow.toarray().flatten()
Out[254]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

2d dense `matrix`:

```
In [255]: arow.todense()
Out[255]: matrix([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

still 2d:

```
In [256]: arow.todense().flatten()
Out[256]: matrix([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

A `np.matrix` 'shortcut':

```
In [257]: arow.todense().A1
Out[257]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

There is a move in `scipy` to convert  to array like objects, e.g. `lil_array`, but that's still a work in progress.

```
In [259]: atx = scipy.sparse.lil_array(mtx)

In [260]: atx
Out[260]: 
<10x10 sparse array of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 0 stored elements in List of Lists format>

In [261]: atx.getrowview(0)
Out[261]: 
<1x10 sparse array of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 0 stored elements in List of Lists format>
```

Still no `flatten`.